# Delete hangs in C++ linked list data Struc

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am having a problem with the following code.  I need to search first the record then delete it:

It always delete the last record. Even if I want to delete the first any rcord in the middle

```
string NameForSearch1;

                     cout<<"Enter Your Friend's Name:      "<<endl;
                     cin>>NameForSearch1;

                     tempRec->namePerson=NameForSearch1;

                     if (tempRec==firstRec){//delete the head

                                      tempRec->next=firstRec;
                                      firstRec=tempRec->next;
                                      delete tempRec;
                                      DisplayRec();
                                      }

                     else if (tempRec->next==NULL ){//delete the last record

                                      tempRec2=firstRec->next;
                                      while(tempRec2->next!=tempRec){
                                            tempRec2 = tempRec2->next;
                                      }
                                      tempRec2->next=NULL;                                         
                                      delete tempRec;


                                      }
                     else {
                          //delete anyrecord
                                          tempRec2=firstRec->next;
                                          while(tempRec2->next!=tempRec){
                                                                         tempRec2 = tempRec2->next;
                                                                         }             
                                          tempRec2->next=tempRec->next;
                                          delete tempRec;

                                          }
```

Comment: If the delete is hanging, then it might be that the destructor for one of the records is what's hanging.  If you're not sure it's the deleter, it might be that your linked list has a cycle in it that's making your loop hang.

Comment: first, you should not name your variables that way. tempRec2, tempRec and so on. next, your delete iteration should not differ where the "to be deleted" item is

Comment: I have tried to delete the last node with else if (tempRec->next==NULL){//delete the last record and it's working right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I am finally able to get the right code:

```
string NameForSearch1;

                     cout<<"Enter Your Friend's Name:      "<<endl;
                     cin>>NameForSearch1;

                     tempRec=firstRec;

                     if (tempRec->namePerson==NameForSearch1){//delete the head

                                      firstRec=tempRec->next;
                                      delete tempRec;
                                      DisplayRec();
                                      }

                     else 
                     {
                          while (tempRec!=NULL && tempRec->namePerson!=NameForSearch1){
                                               tempRec2=tempRec;
                                               tempRec=tempRec->next;
                                       }

                                       if (tempRec==NULL)
                                       {
                                                         cout<<"NO RECORD FOUND";
                                       }
                                       else if (tempRec->namePerson==NameForSearch1)
                                       {
                                            tempRec2->next=tempRec->next;
                                            delete tempRec;     
                                        }
                       }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
tempRec2=firstRec->next;
while(tempRec2->next!=tempRec){
  tempRec2 = tempRec2->next;
}
```

To find the node to be deleted you are comparing the address of the node. Since `tempRec` is a different object you'll never find it in the linked list.

Instead you should be comparing the `NameForSearch1` with the data in each node.

Also your while loop condition is poorly constructed as it allows you to run past the end of the list. You need to ensure you've not reached end of the list.

Comment: I have tried to delete the last node with else if (tempRec->next==NULL){//delete the last record and it's working right..

Comment: it always delete the last record